# What does 'Kokanastha' mean here and meaning of shloka?

Tags: shloka, prayer, shani, meaning

> ॥ शनीची प्रार्थना |। कोकणस्थ: पिंगलो ब्रभु: कृष्णो रौद्रौडन्तको यम: ।
> सौरि: शनैश्वरो मन्द: पिप्पलादेन संस्तुतः ॥ १ ॥ नमस्ते कोकणस्थाय
> पिंगलाय नमोस्तुते। नमस्ते बश्लुरुपाय कृष्णाय च नमोःस्तु ते ॥२॥

I want to know what exactly 'कोकणस्थ:' mean here? This is a 'shani prathana'. The first two lines of the sholka are given above which refer to the word 'kokanastha'.

**What is the meaning of the Shloka?**

---

EDIT: The correct word is कोणस्थ and NOT कोकणस्थ. कोणस्थ as well as पिंगलो are the names of Shani Deva.

Comment: The actual word in the prayer is "Konastha कोणस्थ पिंगलो " and not "Kokanastha कोकणस्थ" that means people who are living in konkan region of Maharashtra.

Comment: Ok. I copied it from a book and it clearly mentions  कोकणस्थ: . Then I gave the link as a reference where its कोणस्थ . Now the question is which one is really correct and what does it mean?

Comment: In that case it's the misprint in the book you are having. The Wikisource link you provided and quick google search both will return with the word Konastha.

Comment: Yes, it's a wrong print. I got that कोणस्थ is other name of shani deva. Please provide with the meaning of shloka. Thank you. Mostly the first two lines.

Comment: Chit paavan and other communities are konkanastha.

Comment: Thank you but, I know that. I want shlokas meaning,the problem of कोकणस्थ and कोणस्थ has been solved. Even पिंगलो is the name of shani.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to translate it myself and find its meaning, any suggestions and revisions will be highly appreciated.

> कोणस्थ: पिंगलो बभ्रु:
> कृष्णौ रौद्रोंतको यम:
> सौरी: शनिश्चरो मंद:
> पिप्पलादेन संस्तुत:

O Shani dev, you are known to be Kōṇastha and piṅgala, known by babhru and Krushna known to be Raudrōntak and Yama also by Sauri, Śanaiścar, manda and Pippalād, O Shani dev you are admired with these ten names!

> नमस्ते कोणसंस्थाय
> पिंगलाय नमोस्तुते

I offer salutation to that one, to Kōṇastha
I offer salutation to that one, to piṅgalō

> नमस्ते रौद्रदेहाय
> नमस्ते चांतकायच

I offer salutation to that one, who has body like a rudra. I offer salutation to that one, who shocks us.

> नमस्ते मंदसंज्ञाय
> नमस्ते सौरयेविभो

I offer salutation to that one, who is slow and dull I offer salutation to that one, who is son of sun god.

> नमस्ते यमसंज्ञाय
> शनैश्चर नमोस्तुते

I offer salutation to that one, who is brother of yama, I offer salutation to that one, who is Śanaiścar.

> प्रसादं कुरु देवेश:
> दीनस्य प्रणतस्यच

O lord, Provide me with the fruit.